# Is it technically sound to clone a git repository directly from the .git folder?

Tags: git

Is it technically sound to clone a git repository directly from the .git folder, eg

`git clone username@somehost:/home/username/workdir/.git` ?

In addition to that is it right to rename it to a non-hidden folder and use it as a remote, ie `mv .git propername.git`  then do a `git clone username@somehost:/home/username/workdir/propername.git`?

I assume that once the `.git` directory renamed to `propername.git` it vanishes as a git repo for the working directory. What stops propername.git for being the working repository for the directory that contains it?

Comment: May I ask why you want to clone directly from `/workdir/.git` instead of just passing `/workdir`? As for taking a `.git` folder and making it non-hidden, one way you could do that is to just make a bare clone of it.

Comment: So I just tested out the idea of cloning directly from `/workdir/.git` instead of simply `/workdir`: it looks like **Yes**, you can do it. Tested on Windows 7 using msysgit Bash with git version 1.9.0. Git is smart enough to figure out what to clone either way.

Comment: I want to know if there any internal differences in the structure and contents of a `.git` directory which is in a working directory as a opposed to  `remote.git` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do it (even if it is technically possible)

Simply [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) the repo while given the destination folder any name you want.

```
git clone /my/repo/url(/.git if you want) myDestinationFolder.
```

Here, "`myDestinationFolder`" can be "`propername`".

Note that "`propername.git`" is, by convention, reserved for **[bare repo](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/sitaramc/sitaramc.github.com/blob/dce410b2a2804723676db9cabd7bb506b6d9ba05/concepts/bare.html)** (repo without a working tree, meaning without any file checked out):

```
git clone --bare /my/repo/url(/.git if you want) propername.git
```